# Spree Paypal Integration Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree-paypal-express

I am using Spree for my E-Commerce.

I have to integrate Paypal Payment Gateway. The tutorial that
I followed was [Paypal Integration with spree][1]
  [1]: https://github.com/spree-contrib/better_spree_paypal_express. I had successfully created sandbox account. When I go for transaction all flows work fine but after I am redirected back to my own site, it throws an error "NoMethodError in Spree::PaypalController#confirm", I don't see this controller in my code and that tutorial link didn't do anything to create this one.

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry. This is not a general issue.

Error was because of my code. Paypal did work fine and redirected fine.

I just had to fix my logic to handle this redirection of paypal using spree.